# ViewModel with IEnumerable<child> member not bound correctly on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model which contains an IEnumerable of a child view model. When I create an edit form for the parent and children, then post it, only the parent part of the view model is populated; the IEnumerable property remains null.

The view models:

```
public class FamilyViewModel 
{

    public int idFamily { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<MemberViewModel> Members { get; set; }

}

public class MemberViewModel 
{

    public int idMember { get; set; }
    public int idFamily { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

FamilyController.cs

```
 [HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var family = unitOfWork.FamilyRepository.Single(f => f.idFamily == id);
    FamilyViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<family, FamilyViewModel>(family);
            /* at this point, viewModel.Members is populated correctly */
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FamilyViewModel viewModel)
{
    /* at this point, viewModel.Members is null */
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Edit.cshtml:

```
@model FamilyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.EditorFor(s => Model, "Family")

@foreach (MemberProfileViewModel m in Model.Members)
{
   @Html.EditorFor(o => m, "Member")
}

@Html.Submit()
}
```

The form is generated correctly. If I recast the Edit method to use a FormCollection, the values for both Family and each Member are received correctly. However, I'd prefer to use the strongly-typed ViewModel.

One possibly relevant piece of info: each child form control has the same ID ; that is, there are `<INPUT TYPE="text" ID="m_FirstName">` for *every* MemberViewModel -- they aren't indexed in any way, which I would have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155747/viewmodels-list-is-null-in-action).  I put the solution I used in the body of my question.  I believe it might be helpful to you as well.  By eliminating that `foreach` the view elements end up being about to be bound back to the underlying viewmodel.  Hope that is helpful to you.